# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: angular

I was following a tutorial about Angular + Firebase i stopped in a datatable error.
the package name

> npm install angular-4-data-table --save

[Error Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNzyj.png)

UPDATE--------

```
import { Component, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTable } from './table.component';
import { HEADER_TEMPLATE } from './header.template';
import { HEADER_STYLE } from "./header.style";


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id +'',
  selector: 'data-table-header',
  template: HEADER_TEMPLATE,
  styles: [HEADER_STYLE],
  host: {
    '(document:click)': '_closeSelector()'
  }
})
export class DataTableHeader {

    columnSelectorOpen = false;

    _closeSelector() {
        this.columnSelectorOpen = false;
    }

    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => DataTable)) public dataTable: DataTable) {}
}
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: please do check, i updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove folder node_modules

```
npm i // install all packages from package.json
npm install angular-4-data-table --save // install your addidtional package
```

Second thing - you probably have errors in header.component.ts etc. Please post your code.

Comment: still got the errors, i have no errors in the header.component, is it maybe that i use angular6 and i use this angular-4-data-table?

Comment: Maybe this elements are not compatible